# Using node.js to display number of current users

Tags: node.js

I've somehow managed to scrape together a local node server. All I'm trying to do is when a user connects to the server, to update an integer. I just can't find what keeps track of current users within the node.js code.

```
if(newUserConnects){
    currentUsers += 1;
}
else if(userDisconnects){
    currentUsers -= 1;
}
```

I'm very very new to server side programming (I've done a little php, but nothing that interacts directly with sever requests).

Comment: Well the user connects to the server and then after a short while disconnects, what's the use case.. ? Are you maybe referring to a websocket server, where users stay connected? (for example a chat?)

Comment: The use is simply to update a DOM element to display the number of current users on the site. So <p>(Dynamic integer here)</p>, would just display the number of users on the site in real time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want to look at using [socket.io](http://socket.io). It provides hooks into things that can easily count and update the code.

I built an app that does this:
http://xjamundx.no.de

The source code is here: https://github.com/xjamundx/CollabPaintJS/blob/master/server.js

See what I do with the count variable.

```
var count = 0
socket.on('connection', function(client) {
    count++;
    client.broadcast({count:count})
    client.on('disconnect', function(){
        count--;
    })
})
```

Hope that helps!

The client side code is here: https://github.com/xjamundx/CollabPaintJS/blob/master/public/collabpaint.js

FYI, my app was built with an earlier version of socket.io so the syntax has changed slightly!

Comment: what about race condition?

Answer (score 6):

Thank you Jamund, really simple and effective solution. Here is my code:

**server.js** *(Node-0.6.6)*

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(7777);
var count = 0

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    count++;
    io.sockets.emit('message', { count: count });

    io.sockets.on('disconnect', function(){
        count--;
        io.sockets.emit('message', { count: count });
    })
});
```

**client.js** *(jQuery 1.6.4)*

```
var socket = io.connect('http://domain.com:7777');
socket.on('message', function (data) {
    console.log(data.count);
});
```

Comment: I think io.sockets.on('disconnect'...) should be socket.io('disconnect'...)

Answer (score 0):

Tested and works with:

- Node v0.12.2 (server)
- Socket.io v0.9.17 (server)
- jQuery v1.11.3 (client)

**server.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
var count = 0

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    count++;
    io.sockets.emit('message', { count: count });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        count--;
        io.sockets.emit('message', { count: count });
    })
});
```

**client.js**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
socket.on('message', function (data) {
    console.log(data.count);
});
```