# Count number of online users with nodeJS and Socket.io without duplicates

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm having trouble displaying the **correct amount** of online users. [A question similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449026/using-node-js-to-display-number-of-current-users) have shown me that I can count the users this way:

```
var count = 0
  socket.on('connection', function(client) {
  count++;
  client.broadcast({count:count})
  client.on('disconnect', function(){
    count--;
  })
})
```

The issue I'm constantly running into with that method is that when a user happens to reload the page too quickly, the counter pulls in too much it can throw out.

[image]

As you can see, on the right side of the image, a user spammed the reload and it caught more users online than there actually is. (There was only one user on the server at this time)

**My question is** is there a better or more reliable way to count the exact amount users online without the extra 'virtual users', without using the `users++`/`users--` method?

Comment: You could always check their IP addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they're logging in as a user, then you should authenticate them to the socket. Use that authentication to see if they already have a session, and disconnect them decrementing the count, before you increment it again with the new session.

An example below. The `clients` objects stores the connected clients, with values being the sockets they're connected to.

```
var clients = {};
socket.on('connection', function(client) {
  //Authenticate the client (Using query string parameters, auth tokens, etc...), and return the userID if the user.
  var userId = authenticate(client);

  if ( !userId ) {
    //Bad authentication, disconnect them
    client.disconnect();
    return;
  }

  if (clients[userId]) {
    //They already have a session, disconnect
    clients[userId].disconnect();
  }

  //Set session here
  clients[userId] = client;

  client.broadcast({count: Object.keys(clients).length})
  client.on('disconnect', function(){
    delete clients[userId];
  })
})
```

Comment: `authenticate() is not defined`, does this function come in a package?

Comment: authenticate is written by you silly! I don't know how your database/setup is configured.

Answer (score 3):

Could do this pretty cleanly with the Observable pattern (using RxJS v5 here):

```
const { Observable } = require('rxjs')

const connections = Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'connection').mapTo(1)
const disconnections = Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'disconnect').mapTo(-1)

// emit 1 for connection, -1 for disconnection
Observable.merge(connections, disconnections)
  .scan((total, change) => total + change, 0) // emit total
  .subscribe(count => client.broadcast({ count }))
```