# Update database before leaving a page in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to develop an attendance management page where I want to update my MongoDB database every time when the user leaves the page.

I found unload function in some answers, but cannot realize how to use it in Node.js.

How can I do this using Node.js framework in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do it from server side, sending request from client before he leaves the page is a bad approach. There are many ways how client can disconnect without sending any request, like connection lost, killing process etc.

Maybe consider different approach, like sending an ajax request as an indication that user is still on page?

Or you could look around for existing solutions, maybe something like [Using node.js to display number of current users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449026/using-node-js-to-display-number-of-current-users)
 could help.